# Auto reload flask server every half hour

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, reload

I am creating a restful api using flask. I have a some data operations that need to be run before the server starts so that calling the api wont load the data again and again.

However, the data also updates via a cronjob. Since the updated data is the input the variable remains static as long as the flask app runs.

I am aware that the flask app reloads on code change but is there a way to make it reload periodically?

Comment: Flask reloads on code change only in debug mode, which you should not use for production.

Comment: Is caching not an option? Maybe you need to tell us more about your use case. How long do the "data operations" take?

Answer (score 0):

One possible, but maybe not the best solution could be:

- run your Flask app via Supervisor ( http://supervisord.org/ )
- after the cronjob finishes, kill your Flask app
- Supervisor will automatically re-start your Flask app